# ComboBox data types supported

Tags: c#

Can I set the data type for a Value of a ComboBox?

I'm have a long list of keyCodes I want to use in the RegisterHotKey() function, which takes an uint VK data type.

```
RegisterHotKey(_hWnd, 1, (uint)fsModifiers.Control, (uint)Keys.Insert);
```

I set my combobox value as "(uint)Keys.Insert". Then I assign the value to a string variable and try to use the variable cast as (uint) in the RegisterHotKey function but I keep getting data type errors.

Either I'm not casting right or this can't be done?

Thanks...

```
        cboHotkeyModifier.ValueMember = "Value";
        cboHotkeyModifier.DisplayMember = "Text";
        items = new[] { 
            new { Value = "", Text = "" },
            new { Value = "Shift", Text = "Shift" },
            new { Value = "(uint)fsModifiers.Control", Text = "Control" },
            new { Value = "Alt", Text = "Alt" }
            };


        cboHotkey.ValueMember = "Value";
        cboHotkey.DisplayMember = "Text";
        items = new[] { 
                        new { Value = "D0", Text = "0" },
                        new { Value = "D1", Text = "1" },
                        new { Value = "D2", Text = "2" },
                        new { Value = "D3", Text = "3" },
                        new { Value = "D4", Text = "4" },
            };
        cboHotkey.DataSource = items;

        keyData = cboHotkey.SelectedItem;
        keyModifier = cboHotkeyModifier.SelectedItem;

        RegisterHotKey(_hWnd, 1, keyModifer, keyCode);
```

Comment: Here is the code that creates the combobox for the fsModifier selection:

            cboHotkeyModifier.ValueMember = "Value";
            cboHotkeyModifier.DisplayMember = "Text";
            items = new[] { 
                new { Value = "", Text = "" },
                new { Value = "Shift", Text = "Shift" },
                new { Value = "(uint)fsModifiers.Control", Text = "Control" }, // <--- I'm trying to use this one
                new { Value = "Alt", Text = "Alt" }
                };

Comment: combobox hotkey:

            items = new[] { 
                          new { Value = "Home", Text = "Home" },
             new { Value = "(uint)Keys.Insert", Text = "Insert" }, // <--- I'm trying to use this one
                          new { Value = "Left", Text = "Left Arrow" }, // Left Arrow
                      new { Value = "OemMinus", Text = "Minus" },
                            new { Value = "Up", Text = "Up Arrow" }, // Up Arrow
                          new { Value = "Oem5", Text = "Vertical Char" }
                };

Comment: public void RegisterHotKeys()
        {
            string keyModifer = "(uint)fsModifiers.Control";
            string keyCode = "(uint)Keys.Insert";
            RegisterHotKey(_hWnd, 1, keyModifer, keyCode);
        }

Comment: I know...how do I get a larger area to write into?